# How to show symfony validation errors?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.7

I try to visualize my error messages from the validator.
When i write the following example:-

```
{{ form_errors(form.pGWeek) }}
```

it works fine and i get the message. But my form has 200 fields and so it's not practical.

So i want to iterate over an Array with all messages, at the end of the form like this:

```
{% if form.name.vars.errors|length > 0 %}
  <ul class="form-errors name">
   {% for error in form.name.vars.errors %}
        {{ error }}
 {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endif %}
```

But i did not get some messages. As well i tried some another versions.. but nothing worked. I'm using Symfony 2.7.

Can give me somebody a tip?

Thanks for a short feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you just want to show all errors for all children of a form without displaying them beside each input field?
Then you could iterate over all the `children` of your `form`, check if any `errors` appeared on this `children` and if so, iterate over all `errors` of this `children`. That could be something like that:

```
   {% for children in form.children %}
       {% if children.vars.errors is defined %}
           {% for error in children.vars.errors %}
               {#{{ dump(children) }}#}
               {#{{ dump(error) }}#}
               {{ dump(children.vars.name ~ ': ' ~ error.message) }}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
```

Which result in an error like `description: This value should not be blank.`.

Answer (score -1):

You can make that loop and condition in your controller using dependency injector, and then in your view you iterate that array of errors and put it into a div o wherever you want, I guess there is something like this:

```
$errors = $this->get('validator')->validate(yourObject);
        if (!empty($errors)) {
            foreach ($errors as $error)
                throw new \Exception($error->getMessage());
        }
```

That is if you want to stop the process and get an Exception, but you want to show that errors, then you make something similar, you only needs to delete that foreach and render your twig template and give it the $errors variable, in your template then you only need to make a for loop for get the errors!

Comment: An Exception? I see helmi is using the Symfony Form Component and it won't throw an Exception, but will return the errors, so you can use `{{ form_errors() }}`. This does not answer the question.